# Lenovo G50-80 Ubuntu 14.04 low sound input

Tags: 14.04, sound, lenovo, skype, alsa

Good afternoon.

I've bought a Lenovo G50-80, and I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and my sound input is too low, so I can't use skype. I've read several posts about it, testing with alsamixer's values and with gstreamer-properties, without obtaining good results. However, in Windows it works fine, so I don't know if somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try out pulseaudio, it might help playing with the settings.
Type in to install:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Comment: Hi @Gogo57. I had already install pulseaudio. This is the output when I try these commands:         
$ pulseaudio:     
``E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.    
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.``    
    
$ sudo pulseaudio:     
``W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).      
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory not accessible: Permission denied``    
    
Thanks!

Comment: @Alejandro Try out typing in pulseaudio in the Run program, or searching in the Media/Sound&Video section(not sure how it goes on Ubuntu). It should be opened through that.

Comment: Hi @Gogo57. I've found PulseAudio Volume Control in Sound & Video section and I can run it! What is the next step? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can anybody help me please? I can't use a lot of applications as skype... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem of left and right mics cancelling each other.

Click with the right mouse button on the loudspeaker icon next to the clock and choose "Volume control" settings, then unlock the mic channels and put left max and right to 30%. Try it that way. It solved my issues.